# Xcode - Up or Down card game (Swift)

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to make a higher/lower card game in Xcode where you get a card displayed, and guess if the next card is gonna be higher or lower by pressing an up or down button, if you guess right it displays a new card, if you guess wrong it stops, but I'm having some issues. Some times, even if I guess wrong, it just displays a new card instead of stopping (usually only happens when guessing down) 
my code looks like this:

```
class UpOrDown: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var upOrDownScore: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var cardImage: UIImageView!


let clubsCards = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "AC"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "2C"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "3C"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "4C"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "5C"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "6C"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "7C"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "8C"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "9C"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "10C"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "JC"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "QC"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "KC")]

var currentCardNumber = 0
var nextCard = 1
var startingCard = 0

//generate random card
func randomCard() {
    nextCard = Int.random(in: 0...12)
}

//generate starting card
func randomStartingCard() {
    startingCard = Int.random(in: 0...12)
}


@IBAction func startTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    randomStartingCard()
    cardImage.image = clubsCards[startingCard]
    currentCardNumber = startingCard + 1



}

@IBAction func cardUp(_ sender: UIButton) {
    randomCard()

    if nextCard >= currentCardNumber {
        cardImage.image = clubsCards[nextCard]
        currentCardNumber = nextCard + 1
        print(currentCardNumber)

    } else {
        print("wrong, next card was: " + "\(nextCard + 1)")
        print("current card number: " + "\(currentCardNumber)")
        cardImage.image = nil

    }
}


@IBAction func cardDown(_ sender: UIButton) {
    randomCard()

    if nextCard <= currentCardNumber {
        cardImage.image = clubsCards[nextCard]
        currentCardNumber = nextCard + 1


        print(currentCardNumber)
    } else {
        print("wrong, next card was: " + "\(nextCard + 1)")
        print("current card number: " + "\(currentCardNumber)")
        cardImage.image = nil
    }

    }
}
```

does anyone see what I have done wrong?

Comment: I don't understand the use of currentCardNumber  and why you set it to nextCard + 1

Comment: im not sure if i did it right but i have a variable containing all the cards, so i added 1 to get their right position, so for example if nextCard is 2, it would give me card number 3 instead of 2, as it starts on 0.

Comment: You are adding +1 to the currentCardNumber but not nextCard variable. But comparing them. Assume on initialize, startingCard is 2, you assigned it to currentCardNumber 2 + 1 = 3. Now, on cardUp or cardDown, you get a random card, nextCard = 2. Normally, they should be equal, it won't compare properly since you increased currentCardNumber.

Comment: thank you so much, i understand a bit more now. do you have any suggestion to what i should set it as? its been bugging me for the last 2 days so I cant even think straigth now

Comment: Skip the  +1 and only assign `currentCardNumber = nextCard`. Also as an extra, you should validate if the generated card is equal to the current card and if so generate a new one since duplicates doesn't exists. But that's for later when you have solved your current issue :)

Comment: I think you increase them to get a variable from the clubCards array. So, you can also add +1 to the nextCard variable.

Comment: does any of you have discord or anything where we could chat? i still can't figure it out. i would be happy to pay for some help if thats wanted

Comment: under my if statement where i display a new image if the guess is correct, what should I put there? currentCardNumber = nextCard, but something else?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the properties `nextCard` and `startingCard` because you don't need them. Then change the card generator function to

```
func randomCard() -> Int {
    return Int.random(in: 0...12)
}
```

Change the `startTap` to

```
let start = randomCard()
cardImage.image = clubsCards[start]
currentCardNumber = start
```

and change the `cardUp` function to

```
let next = randomCard()

if next >= currentCardNumber {
    cardImage.image = clubsCards[next]
    currentCardNumber = next
    print(currentCardNumber)
} else {
    print("wrong, next card was: " + "\(next + 1)")
    print("current card number: " + "\(currentCard + 1)")
    cardImage.image = nil
}
```

and change the other method so it similar to this one. As you see I use the actual values when comparing and accessing the array and only do +1 when displaying the values, this makes the logic simpler.

Comment: thanks for helping me!! i changed my code now but still it doesnt work perfectly. maybe i changed it wrong, could you take a look? 

https://imgur.com/a/AUQsqqv

Comment: * i know i set the cardDown function if statement wrong with > instead of <, but still doesnt work :(

Comment: I can't access imgur right now. Take a look at my code and try to understand what it does instead of just copying it and see if that helps finding the bug(s). ...or wait a few hours

Comment: im getting close. it works for a few clicks, especially when I go up and guess right, some times when  i guess down and its correct, it works, but if I go down one more time after that it just stops working

Comment: for example one simulation: i start with currentCardNumber as 12. then i press down, and I get this:

- wrong, next card was: 4
- current card number: 10

Comment: @lamalama69 You don't need to inform me about every step of your progress and, again, try to understand the code I have posted and what it does. Implementing the cardDown method should be trivial. it is only one character that differs in the code

Comment: @lamalama69 I looked at your image and >= should be <= in the cardDown method